# In .NET what could overflow to yield the number '-2147479552'?

Tags: .net, casting, overflow

In .NET what could overflow to yield the int '-2147479552'?

The exact InvalidOperationException is

System.InvalidOperationException: Value '0x-2147479552' cannot be converted to System.Int64.

I am guessing that what followed 0x was a string that got cast to an int, but what could it have been?

Comment: What is the exact operation that triggered said exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No idea, it depends entirely on the code.

But, interestingly, that number is `4096 - 231` so I'd be looking for the number 4096 somewhere in the code base.

And I'm not sure I agree totally with your comment:

> what followed 0x was a string that got cast to an int.

I suspect it started as an (overflowing) `int`, got cast to a string, then had `0x` prefixed before being passed to `Int64.Parse()` or something similar.

Why you would take a base-10 number and prefix it with `0x` is a bit of a mystery.

But, given that the exception should provide you with a line number, it should be possible to track back from there to find the errant operation.

Answer (score 1):

-2147479552 means your int is too large.

2^31-1-4095 = 2147479552

Which is MAX INT size.

You can not convert an INT to 64INT if the INT is already too big.

Comment: I don't think this is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it was 0x-2147479552? Negative hex doesn't really make much sense... The decimal value -2147479552 is 0x80001000, which can be failure to load an assembly or module.  0x80001000 shows up in a number of other contexts too. Some of the offending code might help.

I did find one bit of C code which uses 0x80001000 to indicate negative int64 overflow

[link](http://www.1pils.de/software/c__basic__math_8h.html)

```
 doubleToInt64  (   const double    value,      double *    intDbl,
        BM_STATUS *     bms     )    
 Output
     status = 0x80001000 (negative int64overflow )
```

Not sure that .NET math uses this convention - MSDN notes

> OverflowException uses the HRESULT COR_E_OVERFLOW, which has the value
>   0x80131516.

InvalidOperation is 0x80131509, so it's not that either.